# how to count number of fb likes and show on a web page in php

Tags: php

How to count number of `f/b` likes and show on a web page
I have tried using access token but failed.

Any help would be appreciated!!
Thank you

I've tried:

```
<?php $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/app-id"';
echo '['.$url.']: '.json_decode(file_get_contents($url))->{'likes'}; ?>
```

And other codes.

But shows only this error:

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, just call this function with your page id and access_token

**First Answer**

```
<?php 
function fbLikeCount($id,$access_token){
    //Request URL
    $json_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'?fiel‌​ds=likes&access_token='.$access_token;
    $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
    $json_output = json_decode($json);

    //Extract the likes count from the JSON object
    if($json_output->likes){
        return $likes = $json_output->likes;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
//This Will return like count of Facebook page
echo fbLikeCount('page_id','access_token');
?>
```

**Second Answer**

```
function fbLikeCount($id,$access_token){
    //Request URL
    $json_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'?fields=fan_count&access_token='.$access_token;
    $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
    $json_output = json_decode($json);
    //Extract the likes count from the JSON object
    if($json_output->fan_count){
        return $likes = $json_output->fan_count;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
echo fbLikeCount('page_id','app_id|app_secret');
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: @SandhyaSingh great glad to help you and thank you for appreciating my answer... :)

Comment: hello Manjeet, As I used this code , I used my page ID and access token. It counts number of likes (when I am online to developers.facebook), but code shows -' file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! ' while I logged out. Is there any solution regarding the same? I will be thankfull.

Comment: I am not getting the solution - now it shows 0 likes with same query

Comment: hiii @SandhyaSingh use `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/'.$id.'?fields=likes&access_token='.$access_token` this url and I've also changed in the answer ..

Comment: I am getting error in - line (1) $json = file_get_contents($json_url); and line (2) if($json_output->likes)

Comment: what error you are getting ?? `echo '<pre>'; print_r($json);` and show me what you are getting in it..

Comment: Notice:  Undefined variable: json
Warning:  file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/768966429866169?fiel‌​ds=likes&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBACCTdTyeQDM3ZCBQ8wtduz6hhKu0FdF7ui3NwD4zwbEMigihDD0Dv7vkpS9tYQBAcnmJnpGShrtvoMGKdVLdQJdJVBxqmQyr6nD4J4NJI8IUXZB1geMOVptVvk4miiIPssv87AvskPP4hKkZBaPOmuTUrHPngZDZD): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 

Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object 

0

 Likes

Comment: at last i m getting 0 likes

Comment: do you have facebook app in your developers account ??

Comment: okay, then use app id and app secret id instead of access token like this
`access_token‌​=app_id|app_secret` call `fbLikeCount('768966429866169','app_id|app_secret');`

Comment: okay , thankyou for your support.. I will let you know afterwards

Comment: yeah sure, I'll be there @SandhyaSingh

Comment: Still I am getting same error on localhost and on server - 0 likes

Comment: can i have your app and app_secret ?? let me check this code with your credentials ...

Comment: @SandhyaSingh your app id is wrong, missing two letters in app id please verify this and use correct id this will solve your problem

Comment: hello manjeet, I am glad for your full support. Thankyou so much.. :)

Comment: Yes, Now its working but with previous code using access token. Thankyou soo much  :)

Comment: welcome dear @SandhyaSingh let me know if any problem in coding ;)

Comment: Hello Manjeet, I didn't get why is this happening. sometimes the code fetches the count_likes but sometimes it shows 0 likes.. Require Ans

Comment: hii @SandhyaSingh, I think the prob is with you access token that's why request is aborted and return empty data when token is expired. I prefer you to use `app_id|app_secret` as access token in request.

Comment: @SandhyaSingh I'm leaving now from SO, if any questions text me [HERE](https://www.facebook.com/mjeetbarnala)

Comment: should I use both in (app_id|app_secret) or only one from them?

Comment: hiii @SandhyaSingh you need to use both `app_id|app_secret` combination of these two is same as access token.

Comment: but with using both as u said, I got this error- 'Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in'

Comment: this one: stdClass Object
(
    [name] => Climax BPM Limited
    [id] => 768966429866169
)


Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$likes in C:\xampp\htdocs\finalclimax\about\index.php on line 292

0

 Likes

Comment: show me your code, let me review your code and then we'll discuss about problem paste your code http://pastebin.ca/

Comment: Is there any solution for the same?

Comment: Hello dear @SandhyaSingh, I've found the solution for you and edited the answer please check and try it with `app_id|app_secret`

Comment: to get the number of likes, you now need to use `fields=fan_count` instead of  `fields=likes` as with my app id it is working fine with likes but on your app id it work with fan_count, I think this is due to difference in FB API version.

Comment: awww... thats pretty cool ..thankyou manjeet for your full support with me

Comment: hii @SandhyaSingh working now >?? or these is any issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use FB api to generate LikeBox "box_count".
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening `<body>` tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=HERE-YOUR-APP-ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Place this code wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

You have to generate app id and replace at step 1 with "HERE-YOUR-APP-ID"
Here is example how to generate app id https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following line of code to see the total like of fb page just you need to change the url of the fb page in the given code below

`<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/(here put your fb page url)%2Fedforall&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=225116190942635" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`